# Cypher: Match on multiple relationship types with opposite directions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Newbie question... I am trying to match on multiple relationships with Cypher. I found an [example in the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-on-multiple-rel-types)  which is almost what I want:

```
MATCH (wallstreet { title: 'Wall Street' })<-[:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN person.name
```

In my case the relationships go in opposite directions.

```
CREATE
(a:Entity { name: 'Entity A'),  
(b:Person { name: 'Person B'),  
(c: Entity { name: 'Entity C'),  
(c)-[:ALIAS_OF]->(b),  
(b)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(a)
```

I want to find every Entity to which Person B belongs OR which is an ALIAS_OF Person B and then find products produced by any of these entities

```
MATCH (b:Person { name: 'Person B'}),
(entities:Entity)<-[:ALIAS_OF|MEMBER_OF]-(b),
(products:Product)-[:PRODUCED_BY]->(entities)
RETURN b, entities, products
```

This will only find entities of which b is a member as the alias relationship goes the other direction. How can adapt this? Is it an indication that I should have structured the relationships the same way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you don’t care about the direction of the relationship, the arrow
>   head can be omitted...
>
> https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-relationship

```
MATCH (b:Person { name: 'Person B'})-[:ALIAS_OF|MEMBER_OF]-(entities:Entity),
      (products:Product)-[:PRODUCED_BY]->(entities)
RETURN b, entities, products
```